# How to copy the after executing subset {inner_beams} results value to another subset {inner_beams} to be used in the constrains in the below code?

Tags: cplex

I have tried more and more to get the results of the after executing subset to be used in the constrains with main without generating new models but i cant, so i need help for this .

```
Main {
      //Code here to get the results of the after executing subset {inner_beams} to the other before executing subset {inner_beams2} to be used in the constrains
     }  
{int} inner_beams2;
Subject to
{
const02:
 forall (i in beams: i in inner_beams2)     // {inner_beams2} is the same values of the {inner_beams}
 (beam_firstchannel[i]==beam_firstchannel[i-1]+ beam_nomusedchannel[i-1]); 
}

{int} inner_beams={2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13};  // this is the results of the after executing
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have sub.mod

```
{int} inner_beams=...;

execute
{
writeln("inner_beams=",inner_beams);
}

dvar int x in 0..12;

maximize x;
subject to {
 forall(i in inner_beams) x!=i;
}

execute
{
writeln("x=",x);
}
```

then

```
{int} inner_beams={};
{int} s2={2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13}; 

    main {
      var source = new IloOplModelSource("sub.mod");
      var cplex = new IloCplex();
      var def = new IloOplModelDefinition(source);
     
     
      
      
      var opl1 = new IloOplModel(def,cplex);
        
      var data1= new IloOplDataElements();
     
      data1.inner_beams=thisOplModel.inner_beams;
    
      opl1.addDataSource(data1);
      opl1.generate();

      if (cplex.solve()) {
         writeln("OBJ = " + cplex.getObjValue());
      } else {
         writeln("No solution");
      }
     data1.end();
     thisOplModel.inner_beams.add(opl1.x.solutionValue);
     for(var i in thisOplModel.s2) thisOplModel.inner_beams.add(i);
     opl1.end();
     
     var opl2 = new IloOplModel(def,cplex);
        
      var data2= new IloOplDataElements();
     
      data2.inner_beams=thisOplModel.inner_beams;
    
      opl2.addDataSource(data2);
      opl2.generate();

      if (cplex.solve()) {
         writeln("OBJ = " + cplex.getObjValue());
      } else {
         writeln("No solution");
      }
     data2.end();
    
     
    }
```

gives

```
inner_beams= {}
OBJ = 12
inner_beams= {12 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 11 13}
OBJ = 10
```

which shows you how with the same model you can take some output and use that as input for the next time you call the model

Many [how to with OPL](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-opl-alex-fleischer/)